# Was the Buddhist monk who self-immolated in protest of the Ngo Dinh Diem policies intoxicated?

Tags: vietnam-war

I was watching [Ken Burn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ken_Burns)'s [Vietnam War documentary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Vietnam_War_(TV_series)).

It described [Thích Quảng Đức](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%ADch_Qu%E1%BA%A3ng_%C4%90%E1%BB%A9c), a Buddhist monk whose death was famously filmed after he self-immolated.

The documentary showed [Madame Nhu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madame_Nhu) (Trần Lệ Xuân), suggesting the monk was intoxicated at the time.

[Interview with Madam Nhu on the self immolation of Thích Quảng Đức](https://youtu.be/d_PWM9gWR5E)

> What have the Buddhist leaders done, comparatively? The only thing they have done they have barbecued one of their monks whom they have intoxicated, whom they have abused the confidence [...]

I can't seem to find any supporting or contradictory information. Is this claim verifiable or provably false?

Comment: The Wikipedia article on Trần Lệ Xuân says: *"Known for her harsh and incendiary comments that denounced anti-government protests by some Buddhist sects and the strong U.S. influence and presence in the country..."*. I think this is as far as we will get: that was her style when responding to protests and anti-government actions. I find no mention that an autopsy was performed on Thích Quảng Đức, and no mention of intoxication. She may also have meant it figuratively. So I say: unanswerable, the utterance is most likely false in its literal meaning, may have been metaphoric.